# How to start specific spring batch job with command line

Tags: spring, docker, spring-boot, docker-compose, spring-batch

I have two configured jobs in my spring boot application. I want to trigger a job manually, using a command in my docker-compose.yml to trigger it. To accomplish this first I disable the batch.job.enabled property in my application.yml:

```
batch:
   initialize-schema: always
   job:
      enabled: false
```

I disable it in order to not allow Spring to execute my jobs on application startup.

I'm trying to test my jobs with docker, so in my docker-compose.yml I set this command on my application service to execute when my container is up:

```
command: java -jar batch-application-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar -Dspring.batch.job.names=uploadToS3Job date=2018-06-26 type=MyType
```

This command runs the `uploadToS3Job` with job parameters date and type.

When I run my application with `docker-compose up --build`, spring application runs smoothly but the job is not executed, nothing happens, no crash, no nothing.

But if I set this property equal true:

```
job:
   enabled: true
```

And run `docker-compose up` again with the same command in my docker-compose.yml, both jobs are executed.

I really don't know what to do, all I want is execute a specific job with specific job parameters using a command that I will pass in my docker-compose.

What's is wrong with this command:

```
command: java -jar batch-application-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar -Dspring.batch.job.names=uploadToS3Job date=2018-06-26 type=MyType
```

Or what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: try `--spring.batch.job.names=uploadToS3Job`

Comment: Thank you very much, that's exactly what I needed to do to make it works.

Comment: make it as a valid answer plz

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try

`--spring.batch.job.names=uploadToS3Job`

Comment: Can you add some explanation?

Comment: I change my command at docker-compose.yml file from -Dspring.batch.job.names=uploadToS3Job to --spring.batch.job.names=uploadToS3Job and it works. Im using spring boot >2.xx